# PHP 7.3.8. ZIP extension on MacOS Catalina 10.15

Tags: php, configure, macos-catalina, phpize

I’m trying to use the builtin PHP in MacOS Catalina 10.15 by compiling the ZIP extension by myself.

In the new MacOS Catalina, the `phpize` tool is no longer usable since inside it contains an invalid path to the PHP libraries. The volume `/usr` is mounted read-only, making all the methods used in the past invalid.

I installed [Xcode 11](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/xcode/id497799835) from the AppStore.

Then I created another `phpize` that references Xcode by copiyng it to my Desktop

```
cp /usr/bin/phpize ~/Desktop/
```

then opened it for edit with `vim`

```
vim ~/Desktop/phpize
```

and modified line 8 as follows

```
includedir = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/php"
```

Then, downloaded [php-7.3.8](https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.3.8.tar.xz), the same PHP version built-in on MacOS Catalina 10.15.

After have unpacked the archive file in the Downloads folder, I opened the Terminal up to its folder

```
cd ~/Downloads/php-7.3.8/ext/zip
```

Once inside, launched the customized phpize in order to prepare the ZIP extension to configure

```
~/Desktop/phpize
```

The extension is now configurable. I launched configure with additional path to the required `zlib`

```
sudo ./configure --with-zlib-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/
```

The next step would be compile and install, but I’m still getting the error `php.h file not found`

```
make && make install
```

Maybe there’s still a wrong path somewhere...

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but StackOverflow is _for programming questions_.  You might want to ask on a different stackoverflow site...

Comment: Stackoverflow would be the wrong place, but superuser would fit.

Comment: I would also love an answer to this, although I guess this is not the place.